# How to get Ctrl+Click to Nuclide

Tags: macos, webstorm, atom-editor, nuclide-editor

I'm new to Mac. I would like to know how to add JavaScript code helper and similar to <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> navigation to the Particular Reference -- same as in WebStorm.

Answer (score 0):

The package `hyperclick` adds click based functionality to Atom. If you have nuclide, I believe it's already installed as part of the package.

To get JS specific behaviour, you will also need the provider [`js-hyperclick`](https://atom.io/packages/js-hyperclick). This package tells hyperclick how to behave with JS files, including letting you click on variables to go to where they are initialised.